# How to auto restart my Spring Boot JAR application after shutdown due of Low Memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, shell, jvm

I have a SpringBoot Web server that sometimes shuts down itself when there is not enough memory on the machine.

So how can I automatically restart the application if that happens.

My approach would be to following:

- Listen on the port 8080 where the server is running
- If there is no more process on this port
- Then I would restart the JAR file.

Comment: I don't know if this works since I never tried it, but I know there are some utilities in Spring Boot Dev Tools that should allow this. A quick search revealed this. Maybe it helps: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-automatic-restart-using-spring-boot-devtools

Comment: Have you seen [Java Service Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-overview.html)?

Answer (score 0):

In which server have you your Spring boot running ?
In a linux distribution, you can manage it by using crontab to start at a wished hour and to stop the process too.

Comment: @jh91 yes it's a Linux (Ubuntu). How can I implement something like that.

Comment: On ubuntu, you can try monitoring tools like MONIT. It will exactly what you want. If service is down, it will restart the service

Comment: @Manu You have some good example to create cron jobs here:
https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/
you must run "crontab -e" to enter to your crontab (it's a vi editor)
Then you can write lines like these:

0 17 * * * <cmd you want to execute> // Every day at 5:00 pm it will execute this command, and for instance you can execute your Spring boot app.
In the same way you can stop the process by killing it (not that good but can do the job in a first try)